# Excel: Average values where column values match

Tags: excel, excel-2010, average, matching

What I am attempting to accomplish is this - where Report ID matches, i need to calculate the average of Value, and then fill the rows with matching Report ID's with the average for that array of Value.

The data essentially looks like this:

```
Report ID | Report Instance | Value
11111             1            20  
11112             1            50 
11113             1            40  
11113             2            30  
11113             3            20 
11114             1            40  
11115             1            20 
11116             1            30 
11116             2            40 
11117             1            20
```

The end goal should look like this:

```
Report ID | Report Instance | Value | Average
11111             1            20       20
11112             1            50       50
11113             1            40       30
11113             2            20       30
11113             3            30       30
11114             1            40       40
11115             1            20       20
11116             1            30       35
11116             2            40       35
11117             1            20       20
```

I have tried using average(if()), index(match()), vlookup(match()) and similar combinations of functions, but I haven't had much luck in getting my final output. I'm relatively new to using arrays in excel, and I dont have a strong grasp on how they're evaluated just yet, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This is tagged as Excel 2010.  Excel 2010 has a built in [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple :-)
 Why not using `=sumif(...)/countif(...)`  ?